# Rejecting an Offer

Tags: job-offer

Just went through a round of interviews and liked the company.
But not any more than my current Job.

The offer was lower than I am willing to take to move to a new job. So I am going to send a rejection e-mail. The question is how much detail do I go into? Do I try and explain why or simply say thanks but no (with some extra fluff to be polite).

### Edit:

Based on Joe's comment below.

I think the goal here is provide an opportunity for the new company to make a better offer. But I am not going to be devastated if they don't up their offer. So advice on how to reply in this situation.

1. Do I say no thank you (and hope they make a better offer).
2. Do I say no, with explanation (if so what level of detail do I go into).
3. Do I try and ask for a better offer and specify what I am willing to go for (The trouble here is deciding what Bonus/RSU are really worth to me (in reality very little)).

Are there any things I should watch out for?

---

This is some details about the offer.

Second part of the question is my reasoning sound?

```
Current Salary:    190 + NoBonus  + Stock Options (currently worth nothing)
Offer:             180 + 36 Bonus + 5K RSU (first year)
```

The new offer has RSU which vest over 4 years but are back end waited at 15%/20%/30%/35%.

My argument is that Bonus is nice. But not part of my salary so I can't count on it. RSU are fine but the companies share price has dropped 30% in 3 months and 60% in the last year so I am not seeing any real value there.

So the base salary is lower.
Base + bonus is larger but it assumes I get the bonus which depends on the company/division being profitable.

Though my current stock options are not worth anything. They amount to 0.5% of the company (Current valuation $135,000,000) and if I leave I have to take the gamble that they will be worth something eventually and actually purchase the options (which will be $50K) within 90 days of leaving.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: That's actually a good question. I am not adverse to another offer. But then again historically I don't have a good feeling about trying to push harder (they knew my current base and options position before they made the offer). So let me edit this question to say I am looking for a better offer.

Comment: FWIW, several relatively recent IPO's took off to a high share price while just the principals were able to sell, then dropped to a lower level when the rank and file were able to sell, then went lower than that for a while because the market overall was low, then went back up. I wouldn't discount the RSU's. RSU's at a fixed amount while the share price is low could go through the roof.

Comment: What sort of environment is it ? What is the corporate culture like ? Are the tasks/projects interesting and challenging ? What other benefits do they offer ? And many many more things.... I don't want an answer to these questions, I'm just trying to tell you that there's more to an offer / job / company than money...

Comment: You're not sending a rejection, you're negotiating (or not). Send a counter.

Comment: Is it safe assuming that RSU = Restricted Stock Units? (Please spell out your abbreviations the first time they're used.)

Comment: Rather than say no just ask for whatever money it would take. You're no worse off if they decline.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're not really trying to reject the offer, but get the organization to make a better offer. As the comment by @jimm101 suggests, don't send an outright rejection.  So, go with your option 3 - send something that tells them that you're interested in the job, but that their offer isn't acceptable and make a counter offer that you find acceptable.

A few years ago I was in a similar situation and successfully negotiated an acceptable offer by sending something like the following:

> Dear (HR rep - in my case, adjust as appropriate):
>
> Thank you for your email offering me (position). I enjoyed meeting with your company, am interested in the position, and feel I would be an excellent fit.
>
> Unfortunately, your offer is not one I can accept. For me to leave my current position and join you, I require (whatever salary, options, and benefits you (reasonably) want).
>
> Thank you for your time and attention.
>
> Sincerely yours,
>
> GreenMatt